# Can't get the environment variables in Elixir project

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

I defined a environment variable related to the [guide-started](http://elixir-lang.org/getting_started/mix/1.html),  my *mix.exs* is

```
defmodule Basic.Mixfile do
  use Mix.Project

  def project do
    [app: :basic,
     version: "0.0.1",
     elixir: "~> 0.13.0-dev",
     deps: deps,
     env: [
      dev: [foo: "bar"] ] ]
  end

  # Configuration for the OTP application
  #
  # Type `mix help compile.app` for more information
  def application do
    [ applications: [],
      mod: { Basic, [] } ]
  end

  # List all dependencies in the format:
  #
  # { :foobar, git: "https://github.com/elixir-lang/foobar.git", tag: "0.1" }
  #
  # Type `mix help deps` for more examples and options
  defp deps do
    []
  end
end
```

and then I start the project with `iex -S mix` or `MIX_ENV=dev iex -S mix`, I want to get the environment variable with `:application.get_env(:basic, :foo)` , it turned to `:undefined`; and use `:application.get_all_env(:basic)`, it returned `[included_applications: []]`, there is not the `env` variable. And my question is how should I get the environment value?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `:env` must not be specified in `project` but inside the application one.

```
def application do
  [ applications: [],
    mod: { Basic, [] },
    env: [foo: :bar] ]
end
```

Then you can access it as:

```
Application.get_env(:basic, :foo)
```

In this case, there is no support for specifying the environment for a particular MIX_ENV (like dev or prod). This is exactly why `:env` inside `project` is deprecated. Having two keys being named `:env` with different behaviour is recipe for confusion. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think `Mix.project[:foo]` returns the defined value ("bar") when MIX_ENV is `dev`. However, as the following warning is being displayed at v0.13.1, it may not be the recommended way.

```
"The :env key in Basic.Mixfile project configuration is deprecated"
```

If it's used for configuration setting, https://github.com/phoenixframework/ex_conf has environment-based configuration features too.

Answer (score 1):

Use `env = :application.get_env(:example, Mix.env)`. That will return the keyword list you've defined under the `:dev` key in your mix.exs file. You can then use `Keyword.get(env, :foo)` to extract the individual keys.

Answer (score 1):

It may be overkill for your needs, but Avdi Grimm recently [ported dotenv to Elixir](https://github.com/avdi/dotenv_elixir).